# I'm trying to distribute the content from *ngFor over different html elements, in different divs

Tags: html, angular

I have a set of buttons that are created with the ngFor functionality.

Separate to these buttons there is a set of  that are toggled to visible and invisible when you press these buttons.

What I am trying to achieve is that the content loaded in that second set of divs matches the content of the ngFor-created buttons.
All documentation I find online treates these problems with a table and table rows but that's always within the same Element.
[the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pslf.png)

and the content

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPPme.png)

```
 <div id="map" class="blue">

  <!-- set of buttons filled with data from arrData:-->
  <div *ngFor="let Lore of arrData" id="Content-knop" class="black knop" (click)="LoreToggle()">    
          {{Lore.Name}}
```

So what I am trying to do is load the rest of the data associated with Lore.Name on the component beneath, that is toggled to visible and invisible by the LoreToggle function in the element above.

```
<table>
  <tr>Name <!--Load content from Content-Knop here--></tr>
  <tr>Tribe <!--Load content from Content-Knop here--></tr>
  <tr>Region <!--Load content from Content-Knop here--></tr>
</table>
<div class="green">
  <p>Description <!--load content from Content-Knop here--></p>
</div>
```

I hope this makes sense. I know my code is missing some ng selected functionality somewhere but I can't find a clean, simple solution that matches my criteria,

Comment: Might be me, but I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve exactly. Maybe you can add a little sketch to illustrate it?!

Comment: sure, I will add some screenshots

Comment: hm in short, I am trying to detect the selected data entry from the ngFor and inject the data from that selected data entry into a different html element. does that make sense?

Comment: So if I understand you right, you would want some variable in the class like `content` which will be displayed in your table and fill that on button click?!

Comment: yes but that content is derived from the same dataset (A json file) that fills the arrData that is used in the ngFor functionality. So basically, when I press the button where index = 001, I want the table to fill with the content associated with index = 001.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not quite certain that I fully understand your issue, but to me it sounds as simple as this:

**example.component.ts**:

```js
const arrData = [
  { name: 'name1', tribe: 'tribe1', region: 'region1' },
  { name: 'name2', tribe: 'tribe2', region: 'region2' },
  ...
];

let visibleData;

public toggleVisibleData(data) {
  this.visibleData = data;
}
```

**example.component.html**

```html
<!-- set of buttons filled with data from arrData:-->
<div *ngFor="let lore of arrData" (click)="toggleVisibleData(lore)">    
  {{lore.name}}
</div>
...
<ng-container*ngIf="visibleData">
  <table>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.name }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.tribe }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.region }}</tr>
  </table>
  <div class="green">
    <p>{{ visibleData.description }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Please also notice that I corrected the code to stick to the [Angular coding style guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#angular-coding-style-guide).

Comment: no luck: my ts.

export class LoreComponent implements OnInit {

  private _jsonURL = 'assets/Data.json';
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  arrData: string[];
  let visibleData;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.httpService.get('assets/Data.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrData = data as string[];
      }
    )
}

public toggleVisibleData(data) {
  this.visibleData = data;
}
}

Comment: my html:

<!-- set of buttons filled with data from arrData:-->
<div *ngFor="let lore of arrData" (click)="toggleVisibleData(lore)">
  {{lore.name}}
</div>
...
<div ngIf="visibleData">
  <table>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.name }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.tribe }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ visibleData.region }}</tr>
  </table>
  <div class="green">
    <p>{{ visibleData.Description }}</p>
  </div>

  </div>

Comment: I'm also not sure why I'd need a second set of data entries as the data comes from the same source...

Comment: arrData is an array of objects, not string. please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkftk2) with your code and the issue and post again here. I do not understand what your issue is.

Comment: Well I managed to solve but thanks for your help nonetheless. I ended up having to make two different components, one map with buttons derived from a datase. Each time the button was pressed a new dataset was created based on the Index of that number. This new dataset was then used to fill in the data in the detailed component. The underlying problem was that I'm new to webdevelopment, programming, java, new to everything really so the ways I've learnt to use components and variables is quite limited.. Thanks anyways! If you're curious I can still upload the code to stackblitz.